# Apache doesn´t show Website / Scoreboard is full, not at MaxRequestWorkers

Tags: apache, deployment, linode

i´m running two different Linode Nanode with two websites. Every couple of days i can´t access my website with the browser.

After i reboot the Linodes it works well for the next few days but than i get the exame error. I checked the apache2 log and it says "[Sun Dec 03 15:57:15.314126 2023] [mpm_event:error] [pid 182007:tid 140584127080320] AH03490: scoreboard is full, not at MaxRequestWorkers.Increase ServerLimit." I have the issues at both Linodes.

This is the mpm_event.conf:

StartServers             2
    MinSpareThreads      25
    MaxSpareThreads      75
    ThreadLimit          64
    ThreadsPerChild      25
    MaxRequestWorkers     150
    MaxConnectionsPerChild   0

What can i do? I´m new to the whole hosting world.